# COCI '15 Contest 6 #4 Parovi

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I am solving problem from [here](https://dmoj.ca/problem/coci15c6p4) and I am having difficulty finding a solution for it.
I think what the question says is for every set, there should be a pair ending at / or containing every number from 2 to N, and a number starting at 1. I think the solution would be to use dp, where dp[i] is input for answer i. I try to write recursion but end up missing cases or repeating cases. Any ideas on how to approach this recursion?

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in applying the inclusion-exclusion principle to the number of partition thresholds.

```py
from itertools import combinations
from math import gcd, prod


def parovi(n):
    rel_prime_subsets_between = {
        (a, b): 2 ** sum(gcd(i, j) == 1 for j in range(a + 1, b) for i in range(a, j))
        for b in range(2, n + 2)
        for a in range(1, b)
    }
    return sum(
        (-1) ** k
        * prod(
            rel_prime_subsets_between[(a, b)]
            for (a, b) in zip((1,) + boundaries, boundaries + (n + 1,))
        )
        for k in range(n)
        for boundaries in combinations(range(2, n + 1), k)
    )


print(parovi(2))
print(parovi(3))
print(parovi(4))
```

Comment: your code is quite concise. honestly it is bit difficult to understand for me. I would appreciate if you could explain the idea a bit, or give some link that has the explanation. But still thanks for answer. I am working to deduce what this code does

Comment: @HSSingh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: I am still not able to understand how this works. I know inc-exc principle, but how is it applied is not clear. Can you explain a bit?